# Where to process SQL responses in websites

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I am working on a website which uses multiple MySQL database tables. For now I am using these tables to show their content in tables on multiple pages. In order to create these tables I use JavaScript to make a AJAX request to the server. The php-script does a request to the database and sends the response back to the client. The JavaScript uses this response to create HTML code. So in this case, the JavaScript processes the data (Creates html table from database data).

In the future I want to add more functions like user login with password etc.

So, my question is: What is the best way to process your database data. For example: Should I check if the password is correct in JavaScript (clientside) or in PHP (serverside)?

Please let me know if the question is not clear.

Comment: I would be careful about using so much ajaxif you want your site indexed by search engines

Comment: I'll recommend this excellent book: Learning PHP, MySQL & JavaScript by Robin Nixon. It deals with the issues you mentioned to a great extent. http://it-ebooks.info/book/4681/

Answer (score 1):

The best way to process sensitive data as login password etc...

Is to do it serverside, why ? Because you can never trust the client, javscript can be turned off in the user's browser, fail due to a scripting error, or be maliciously circumvented without much effort.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming

Comment: How about creating the SQL request strings. Is it better to create these in PHP aswell?

Comment: @ArabCheese of course, also never forget to secure the user input variables (GET, POST)

Answer (score 1):

You should never check critical data integrity or safety in clients code, because it can be modified or injected with something else. The general rule in your case is the database stores the data, the PHP server process the data (makes checks, updates so on). JavaScript formats data only so it can be displayed nicely! No business logic.

Any checks made in JavaScript are only for the purpose of not overloading the server-side. For example, why send user login and password if we can detect that the format is wrong?

Edit: as to your SQL question, most certainly yes to PHP. If you send SQL scripts from JavaScript, what will stop someone from sending their own commands to your database? One alternative is to make also some kind of stored functions or procedures in your database.

Comment: Still if you had a perfect connection, low server usage etc. all that stuff could be done on server side via ajax for example. JavaScript is the V in the MVC including any business logic will start a holy war of what should and shouldn't be done by the interface.
P.S As I wrote none critical validation should be done by JavaScript.